# Android: The different API levels

Tags: android, api

I had to implement an App and the first statement of my superior was
that he does not care about the android version (api level) he just
cared about that all the specified functions are implemented.

So the API level need for all those functions was 21 (5.0)

Now... Months later after it came to the decision that the app should
run on samsung galaxy s3 without rooting it (I guess max api 4.1 or 4.3)
i have a problem.

I dont really know all the differences between the api levels so i really
need to ask if it is possible to implement all the functionalities
api 21 offers for the android developers using lower API levels (api level 16 and higher).

Comment: You can not implement all functionalities on older API levels. But usually, the old API levels are completely enough. Google offers the support libraries to make it possible to use new functions on old APIs.

Comment: thats a great hint. i will investigate! thx

Comment: the easiest way to go is to start by changing the target sdk of your project, and see what stops compiling. for each error, you'll see the api level where it was added, and you'll have to figure out how to do without. For some graphical elements, the support library can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer by Richardo Silva is not completely correct - compiling with support library does not guarantee everything will work.

> If you are using the Support library into your project, you don't have to worry with backward compatibility.

- is true in general meaning, but that certainly doesnt mean that just compiling code with support library is enough. To show an example, be sure to call Toolbar from support library `<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar`in xml, instead of classic usage and importing `import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar` in activity.

It's also worth mentioning, that not every feature from L has their implementation in Support Library - you may want to use code checks for version of android running on device and/or use additional libraries for material design (such as [FAB Library](https://github.com/makovkastar/FloatingActionButton) or [Ripple Effect](https://github.com/traex/RippleEffect))

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the Support library into your project, you don't have to worry with backward compatibility.
This library will keep your app working with the later versions of the Android SO.

In fact, the use of this library is a good practice recommended by google itself : http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html

Comment: this is quite wrong. there are many features and individual methods that have been added after 4.1 that are not present in the support library.